# how to deal with include space keys in JSON array when reading in Ansible

Tags: arrays, json, ansible

Below is my JSON file:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "cucm_ip": "1.1.1.1",
            "cucm_option": "DBREPLICATION",
            "cucm_pwd": "123",
            "cucm_user": "123"
        }
    },
    "meta": [
        {
            "DB/RPC/DBMON?": "Y/Y/Y",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "1.1.1.1",
            "PING (msec)": "0.029",
            "REPL.QUEUE": "0",
            "REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details": "(2) Setup Completed",
            "Replication Group ID": "(g_2)",
            "SERVER_NAME": "bopub1"
        },
        {
            "DB/RPC/DBMON?": "Y/Y/Y",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "1.1.1.2",
            "PING (msec)": "0.175",
            "REPL.QUEUE": "0",
            "REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details": "(2) Setup Completed",
            "Replication Group ID": "(g_3)",
            "SERVER_NAME": "bosub1"
        },
        {
            "DB/RPC/DBMON?": "Y/Y/Y",
            "IP_ADDRESS": "1.1.1.3",
            "PING (msec)": "0.293",
            "REPL.QUEUE": "0",
            "REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details": "(2) Setup Completed",
            "Replication Group ID": "(g_6)",
            "SERVER_NAME": "bosub2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get the value from key 'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details', how to achieve this..

I always got fatal error '"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ item.'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details' }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ item.'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details' }}"'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"Get the value from key 'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details'"***

A: Read the JSON from the file into the dictionary

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: data.json
        name: data
```

gives

```yaml
  data:
    changed: false
    invocation:
      module_args:
        cucm_ip: 1.1.1.1
        cucm_option: DBREPLICATION
        cucm_pwd: '123'
        cucm_user: '123'
    meta:
    - DB/RPC/DBMON?: Y/Y/Y
      IP_ADDRESS: 1.1.1.1
      PING (msec): '0.029'
      REPL.QUEUE: '0'
      REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details: (2) Setup Completed
      Replication Group ID: (g_2)
      SERVER_NAME: bopub1
    - DB/RPC/DBMON?: Y/Y/Y
      IP_ADDRESS: 1.1.1.2
      PING (msec): '0.175'
      REPL.QUEUE: '0'
      REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details: (2) Setup Completed
      Replication Group ID: (g_3)
      SERVER_NAME: bosub1
    - DB/RPC/DBMON?: Y/Y/Y
      IP_ADDRESS: 1.1.1.3
      PING (msec): '0.293'
      REPL.QUEUE: '0'
      REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details: (2) Setup Completed
      Replication Group ID: (g_6)
      SERVER_NAME: bosub2
```

---

Put the key *'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details'* into a variable. You don't have to escape special characters if you use single quotes. Declare the variables

```yaml
  rsd: "{{ data.meta|map(attribute=my_key)|list }}"
  my_key: 'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details'
```

gives

```yaml
  rsd:
  - (2) Setup Completed
  - (2) Setup Completed
  - (2) Setup Completed
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    rsd: "{{ data.meta|map(attribute=my_key)|list }}"
    my_key: 'REPLICATION SETUP (RTMT) & Details'

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: data.json
        name: data
    - debug:
        var: data
    - debug:
        var: rsd
```